# Can't deploy vaadin project

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, vaadin

i have a little vaadin project for a school project that originally deployed well and worked.
i am using jboss as 7.1.1, vaadin7 and jdk8. My target platform is a raspberry pi running raspbian os.
so i am using the pi4j library to access the gpio interface of the raspberry and everything worked just fine until i implemented a check for null when creating a new instance of the web page. at first the error was because somehow the "jboss/standalone/deployments/roboterarm.war/WEB-INF/..../classes" directory became empty. afterwards the error came to eclipse as i could not use the pi4j library anymore. i did not touch the libraries and i can't figure out why it suddenly stopped working. i reinstalled eclipse, jboss and redownloaded all the libraries but i still can not use anything, not even in normal java applications!
afterwards i grabbed a copy from SVN that used to work normally but no luck there either, i can not use the pi4j jar-files.

[image: my build path]

everything looks fine to me there, yet it fails to give me code completion or compilation

[image: library does not get loaded]

i also tried creating a new vaadin project and c&p'ing the source code into the new project but the jar files are not recognized there either.

What am i doing wrong? how can i fix this? thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this tutorial, [Controlling the Raspberry Pi’s GPIO Pins from a Web Browser](http://en.paperblog.com/controlling-the-raspberry-pi-s-gpio-pins-from-a-web-browser-439660/) using Vaadin & Tomcat & Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse `buildpath`, clearly indicates that your `JRE` is not properly added. Add your `JRE` to your build path, using the option `Add Library`.

Comment: that's right! i've fixed it but still does not recognize pi4j libraries